# Display Who Follows You on Instagram

Tags: php, instagram, instagram-api

I am trying to create a simple script that displays who a user follows and if that person follows them back or not. Is there a way to fetch this information with Instagram API?

Comment: You can read the [API Docs](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/) for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the relevant [Instagram API docs](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/relationships/#get_users_followed_by)  you should refer to for specifics.

As a rough overview: you will need to register a developer account, create an app, and authorize that app to receive an access token. Once you have that, something like this will do what you want:

```
$userId = "self";

$url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/$user/followed-by?access_token=$accessToken";

$response = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));
$followers = $response->data;
```

Of course you can also use cURL or Guzzle instead.

**Note:** to get a user's follower list that user must authorize your application with `scope=follower_list` to be granted this permission.